# Scanf not reading piped input's first value only as expected (reads as string, expected integer)

Tags: c, bash, pipe, printf, scanf

I would consider myself fairly proficient in C and have been coding in it extensively for a few years now, but during a tutoring session with another student I got stumped on a problem. We are printing Linux device events in one program than trying to read and interpret the data by piping the input of that program into another. I'm hoping I am overlooking something dumb and that you guys can figure it out.

First program's relevant code:

```c
struct input_event event1;
...
// open correct event file and read its values into the input event struct
... 
printf("%d  %zu.%-6zu  %d  %3d  %9d\n", 1, event1.time.tv_sec, event1.time.tv_usec, event1.type, event1.code, event1.value);`
```

Output of first program in the terminal, looks correct.

```
1  1.638837  3   16     -24402
1  1.638837  3   17      23791
1  1.646835  3   16     -25588
1  1.646835  3   17      23753
1  1.654835  3   16     -26378
1  1.654835  3   17      21386
1  1.666836  3   16     -27498
1  1.666836  3   17      20308
1  1.674837  3   16     -29342
1  1.674837  3   17      18248
1  1.682836  3   16          0
```

Programs piped together in bash: `./prog1 | ./prog2`

Second program's relevant code:

```c
int event_num, type, code, value;
double time;
char arr[100];

// this scanf returns 0 on this and following printf is garbage
scanf("%d  %lf  %d  %d  %d", &event_num, &time, &type, &code, &value);

// alternately, this scanf returns 5 as expected and printf works,
//   but my first value is stored in a character array
//   rather than an integer variable as wanted
scanf("%s %lf %d %d %d", arr, &time, &type, &code, &value);
```

It seems as though I can read the `stdin` as an array of strings no problem and I can store most of the input as expected, but I cannot seem to get the first value to be stored as an integer.

Thanks in advance, and let me know if you have any further questions or clarification needed.

I tried different format specifiers including `%*s` and the `%[^0-9]%d` and `getchar()` hoping to remove any junk at the beginning of the string that might be messing stuff up. I have tried changing the type of the variable and the format specifier, but I can never read the first value as anything other than a string.

Comment: Can you minimally reproduce this?

Comment: Use `fgets` to read the whole line and the print the string to see what the real input is.. Perhaps print the decimal value of each character to find "non-printable" characters

Comment: @Fe2O3 sorry, the code is on a remote server and I tried to copy it as faithfully as I could, I have now double checked and added the newline character and character widths to make it an exact match to the code. Sorry I dont have copy and paste set up on the server.

Comment: Instead of piping from one black box to another. capture the output of the first program and add that to this question. Otherwise, it's pure guesswork... (re: '\n'... no worries... this happens... `:-)`

Comment: @Haris sorry for the miscommunication on my part, what I am trying to say is that I want it to be stored as an integer. I want to be able to use %d since I am expecting it to be an integer. However the %d does not store the variable, and scanf fails entirely. But if I store just the first value as a character array, then scanf happily accepts it, stores it and the rest of the values as wanted. Meaning for some reason it can ONLY be stored as a character array and not an int.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Added output to the question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If `scanf()` thinks the first 'element' is a string, then try examining that array of characters. What are the byte values of the "string" up to the null terminator?

Comment: @SupportUkraine Yes, I have tried fgets to read the whole line, and it works, it reads the entire input, and then I can print the entire input as a string using %s in printf, but I dont know what it tells me in regards as to why specifically the first value is read only as a string and not an integer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The input to the second program is obviously not what you think it is. As previously suggested you need to print the exact input. Don't print it as characters as some characters wont produce visible output. Print the integer value of each character instead. Simply write another program that keeps reading a character using `getchar` in an endless loop.

Comment: `while(1) {int c = getchar(); printf("[%c] [%d] [%x]\n", c, c, c }`

Comment: I can't reproduce it.  Identify one failing line, say, `head -1`, then run it through `od -a`.   My guess is there is a prefix or suffix to the first field that is a non-space but doesn't render (like 0x3000).  I suggest you create an double variable 2nd field instead of doing it in the format string.  You may then be able to share a format string constant between sender and receiver.

Comment: **I can't reproduce it.** Try this: `struct input_event event1;

int main(int argc, char**) 
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {       
        printf("%d  %zu.%-6zu  %d  %3d  %9d\n", 1, event1.time.tv_sec, event1.time.tv_usec, event1.type, event1.code, event1.value);
    }
    else
    {
        int event_num, type, code, value;
        double time;
        int q = scanf("%d  %lf  %d  %d  %d", &event_num, &time, &type, &code, &value);
        printf("%d %d\n", q, event_num);

    }

    return 0;
}` Run it as `./a.out | ./a.out a` As expected I get the output `5 1`

Comment: My conclusion is that the problem is in some part of the code that you removed (aka didn't post). I'm voting to close as the question can't be answered with the information provided.

Comment: Best guess is there's some control character at the beginning of the line.  This will be invisible when printed, but will prevent the `%d` from matching (while the `%s` will match it and the digit just fine).

Comment: My guess is you have a UTF-8 BOM at the beginning of the stream or some other initial contents.  I explained some other problems in my answer.

Comment: @ClaySmith: to copy and paste from the server, run `ssh` from a terminal window and  display the code with `less`, then copy+paste from the terminal to the navigator.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks for the tip, I will be honest I know nothing about it, so I will look into that topic and see if that is my issue. Thanks for the lead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging the issue was in part of the code not listed, so I apologize for that, but in my defense I have received toxic feedback before for including too much code in questions and to limit my code to "just the important part". I was using the system() function as: system("clear") which was effecting my stdout buffer only on the first execution, which is why fgets worked as it essentially throws that garbage out so my scanf can proceed as expected. Other uses of the system() function do not effect stdout such as system("reset"), but apparently that one does.

Comment: Your explanation is surprising.  calling `system("clear:);` might indeed have side effects, but unlikely to affect the input stream.  Would you mind updating the question and post the source to the program with the `system("clear")` call that causes the problem?

Comment: Sorry I rarely come on here. I did confirm that system("clear") was the issue. This is best explained because what it is essentially doing is this: printf("\033[2J");. I was printing in one program and cleared the screen and piping it into another, well when reading it from the other program (the one reading in stdout from the pipe), the first thing it would read is the "\033[2J" that the system() function call started the program with. I still feel like it should have been made more clear in the docs. lol This was a hard one to figure out.

Comment: you could try and send the escape sequence directly to the process group terminal device with this: `{ FILE *fp = fopen("/dev/tty", "w"); if (fp) { fprintf(fp, "\033[2J"); fclose(fp); }`

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as *relevant code*... the problem might lie in lines that you did not post. Yet there are multiple issues with the posted fragments:

- the return value of `scanf()` is not tested so one cannot detect conversion errors (actually you document the return values, but I suspect you get them from the debugger).
- it is very difficult to recover from conversion errors when parsing with `scanf` directly. One should read the input one line at a time with `fgets()`, parse it with `sscanf()` and test the return value to detect errors and report the errors with meaningful messages.
- **prog1** use `%zu.%-6zu` to output `event1.time.tv_sec` and `event1.time.tv_usec`. This poses 2 different problems:

  - the types of `tv_sec` and `tv_usec` are not `size_t`, they are system dependent types `time_t` and `suseconds_t`.  You should use `%lu` or `%llu` and convert the fields appropriately. As coded, the program may have undefined behavior.
  - using `%zu.%-6zu` to output a decimal value to be parsed with `%lf` is incorrect because the microseconds are not always output with 6 digits and smaller microsecond numbers will produce fewer decimals that will be parsed with an incorrect value by `%lf`. You should use `%lu.%.6lu` or `%lu.%06lu` instead. As coded, `1` second and `5` microseconds is printed as `1.5`      and read back as `1.5` instead of `1.000005`.

Here is a conversion loop that should make the parsing errors easier to analyze:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int event_num, type, code, value;
    double time;
    char buf[100];
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        int res = sscanf(buf, "%d %lf %d %d %d",
                         &event_num, &time, &type, &code, &value);
        if (res != 5) {
            fprintf(stderr, "parsing error, returns %d: %s\n", res, buf);
            fprintf(stderr, "  initial bytes: %02hhx %02hhx %02hhx\n",
                    buf[0], buf[1], buf[2]);
        } else {
            /* handle the parsed values */
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You could also check for potentially invalid trailing data at the end of the line with an extra `%c` or `%n` conversion.

Here is a wild guess: you might want to check the output stream for an initial byte sequence EF BB BF using a hexdump utility. This sequence is a UTF-8 encoded Byte Order Mark that may have been inserted at the beginning of the output by **prog1** depending on the locale settings.

Comment: Thanks for the response! A couple of notes and clarifications to address your response. I mentioned in response to other comments that I do test the output of scanf and note that when reading the first value as a string I get 5 which correlates correctly to the amount of things I am scanning in, but when I scanf using %d it is zero because it fails on the first value, which is how I know that it is the issue. As far as the relevant code, I only say that as I know this forum is picky about bloated questions and code, and that really is the only part of the code that outputs to the terminal.

Comment: The '-' sign in the printf just left aligns the text and does not impact how it evaluates the expression and the width number is also again not seemingly an issue because it just sets a lower limit on how much space the value will take up on the screen, again, works and is not causing any problems with scanf.

Comment: @ClaySmith: sorry for coming across as picky and patronizing, but most posts with code fragments tend to miss crucial information.  Regarding `fgets()` and testing the return value of `scanf()`, my proposed approach lets the program produce useful error output: if a line fails to convert with a `%d` conversion for the first field, you will get a chance to see its contents.

Comment: @ClaySmith: *The %zu works because it is always going to be greater than or equal to %lu*: You cannot rely on this (indeed it was not the case on 16-bit systems) and it is irrelevant because if `size_t` is larger than `unsigned long` (as in the case in Windows 64-bit systems) values might be passed to `printf` in an incompatible way. Discrepancy between the format spec and the argument type causes undefined behavior. It may seem to work on your system, but this might be a coincidence and another instance might not, whether for the same target or another. Just use `%lu` and cast the arguments.

Comment: @ClaySmith: regarding `%zu.%-6zu` I agree with your explanation of the format `-` flag and width specs but I disagree with your conclusion: the microsecond part must be padded with leading zeroes up to 6 places otherwise it might get converted by `scanf` with `%lf` with the wong value. For example: a `timeval` of `{ 1, 9 }` meaning 1 second and 9 microseconds (`1.000009`), The `printf` format `%zu.%-6zu` would produce `1.9     ` (with 5 trailing spaces) which `scanf` with `%lf` will convert to `1.9`, almost twice the original value.  Using `%lu.%06lu` or `%lu.%.6lu` fixes this problem.

Comment: Wow, thanks again for the follow up! I am learning a lot. I'm re-reading the 2011 C Standard and have come to the conclusion that my understanding of size_t was fundamentally wrong on two fronts. I did not realize how vague and open ended the standard was in regards to size_t. Also I remember learning in school that: "The type's size is chosen so that it can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible array of any type." Rereading that I realized I misunderstood that to mean it was automatically the largest type and now should go revise other code I have worked on in the past!

Comment: I have also updated the code to use the %06lu to match it more correctly with the timeval type.

Comment: I will state however, that while my code now works using fgets() followed by sscanf() and even fgets() followed by scanf, I don't fully understand what the fgets() is doing to solve the issue.

Comment: @ClaySmith: `%lu` is a good choice because type `unsigned long` has at least 32 value bits so it can handle the range of both fields, but you should still add casts to ensure the values are passed as the expected type: `printf("%d  %lu.%6lu  %d  %3d  %9d\n", 1, (unsigned long)event1.time.tv_sec, (unsigned long)event1.time.tv_usec, event1.type, event1.code, event1.value);`

Comment: @ClaySmith: `fgets()` reads the actual contents of the log line, `sscanf` attempts to convert it and, if the conversion fails, `fprintf` outputs the original contents of the offending line, giving a change to observe and understand what the problem is.